# How can I get 'highlighted post' information from my fb profile page in my ios5 app using facebook api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios5

I'm developing an app for iPhone(ios5), where I need the information of the posts I made highlighted in my facebook profile. Using facebook-graph api its possible to get all the data of user profile but is there any way I can get highlighted posts data ? For example I want to count and keep track of how many posts I highlighted in fb timeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[pageid]?fields=posts.fields(timeline_visibility)`

Each highlighted post will have timeline_visibility set to "starred"

Comment: Eventhough the post is highlighted, "timeline_visibility" shows "no timeline unit for this post". Do check it out and update your answer.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM - Can you give me an example post ID where this occurs?  As far as I can see, the answer is still valid.

Comment: {
  "id": "778783268829364", 
  "name": "Bala Subramani M", 
  "feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "timeline_visibility": "no timeline unit for this post", 
        "message": "#Google #loveyou #Santa \nhttps://t.co/DLBADzIba9", 
        "id": "778783268829364_828941783813512", 
        "created_time": "2014-12-12T04:25:00+0000"
      }, 

As you can see, "timiline_visibility" is still unchanged. That post has been highlighted.